# Do asp.net windows server based server uses any udp packets

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net, udp

I am an indie browser mmorpg game developer. I am not using any streaming. Everything is http , web service or ftp.

Now my question is does my server use any UDP packets? I just recently got ddos attack and planning to block all udp packets at network layer if possible.

- Windows server 2008 r2
- .net Framework 4.0
- ASP.net,html,ajax,mssql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO,

HTTP runs only over TCP... so for HTTP access to your server you dont need any UDP ports. 
FTP also uses TCP only (TFTP uses UDP Ports) 
and your WebService (i think you are using WCF or soap) also runs over the HTTP protocol on your IIS.. so also no  - (only if you are working with Windows-Authentication and ActiveDirectory with your WCF, then the IIS has to communicate with the ADS-Server (outgoing udp's), but i think that server is in your environment.. ;) - so u can block external udp packets